# Using OS X Lion - Migrating from Mobile Me to iCloud - Incoming Mail Server issue

Tags: icloud

I have gone through the steps to migrate from Mobile Me to iCloud on my Mac.  The incoming mail server (p99-imap.mail.me.com) is grayed out and cannot be changed.  According to Apple Support, that is not the correct incoming mail server.  Thoughts?

Comment: I have the same mail server for my iCloud account so I don't think there is anything wrong with that. Do you experience actual mail problems?

Comment: Yes, I can't receive any mail.

Comment: Just talked with Apple IT support.  There is an issue with the Apple server.  They told me to wait a few hours and try again.

Comment: I think it will take a few more weeks for all of the issues associated with Mobile Me migration to iCloud to be worked out. I had many "bumps" at first but every one of them is solved and things are working well. I think you'll enjoy iCloud's speed of syncing compared with the old Mobile Me, I know I am.

Answer (score 1):

In mail - preferences - advanced - uncheck 'enable this account'. 
click another account or tab to get dialogue box to save changes.
check 'enable this account' 
click another account or tab to get dialogue box to save changes.
get mail.